# Is there a reason for the sudden change in style in episode 11?

Tags: danna-wakaranai-ken

The animation throughout the first 10 episodes seemed pretty consistent to me.

[image: Image from episode 8] [image: Image from episode 10]

However, episode 11's style had nothing to do with the first 10 episodes (though it was probably consistent throughout the episode):

[image: Image from episode 11] [image: Image from episode 11]

Since this show is filled with references to other anime, it occurred to me that the change in style could be a reference in itself. If so, what was it a reference to?
If not, why the sudden change in style? Was it due to budget or something similar, or did they just decide to go on a different direction for some random reason?

Answer (score 1):

This episode was [done entirely](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=16247) by one person, [Itsuki Imazaki](http://myanimelist.net/people/30623/Imazaki_Itsuki), whose style you might recognize from [Ai Mai Mi](http://myanimelist.net/anime/16169/Ai_Mai_Mi).

Everything involves storyboard, [mise-en-scene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_sc%C3%A8ne), directing, and key animation.

Comment: Ok, but is there a *why* for this? I only insist in the *why* because the first 10 episodes were consistent. If every episode was different, it wouldn't matter that much, but since it was only one, I was wondering if there was a particular reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

**The entire 11th episode is Kaoru's flashback.** Often in Anime (and even Cartoons), flashbacks are usually done in slightly different style or with some effect to differentiate them. Same is the case here.

Even the last scene is a flashback. I say this because **[her hair is dark blue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/why-did-kaorus-hair-color-change)** in this scene.

[image]

Comment: In the scene where Kaoru wakes up in the morning (see the question), he hair is blond, which means it is a scene in the present, but the animation style is the same as the rest of the episode.

Comment: She changed her hair color soon after their wedding, so no, that doesn't mean it's the present. From context, that scene seems to be from the early days of their marriage. Hence, it _is_ a part of her flashback.

Comment: I think it is her in present, having a flashback of her old days in her dream, and waking up appreciating what her husband has done to change her. I don't think she would appreciate so much that she even cried if it were in her early days of marriage.

Comment: The fact that she has blonde hair in some scenes does not mean it is the present, indeed. However, we had seen flashbacks in other episodes with no change in style whatsoever. Do you mean the change happened because the *whole* episode is a flashback? Because the final scene appears to be in the present. And not only because of her blonde hair.